# Need parser for Javascript (used in Java app) to get basic property value information about Ext.define objects

Tags: java, javascript, parsing

I have hundreds of small javascript files that follow the following format where Ext.define defines a javascript class. I need to be able to parse these files in a Java app and get the "SOMECLASSNAME" and the values for various properties like "extend" and "requires". I want to ignore comments and I don't care about the functions.

I have actually already implemented this using regular expressions and it works. However, it's fairly brittle. I've already dealt with issues like files that use " instead of ' and inconveniently placed comments which break the regexes. I would really like to do this using a less brittle solution and that means using a javascript parser.

I've searched using various searches like "java javascript ast parser", but nothing seems to fit what I'm trying to do. The closest I've found is [Using ScriptEngine in java, How can I extract function list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546601/using-scriptengine-in-java-how-can-i-extract-function-list) but that seems to require that the script be runnable and each of these files isn't runnable by itself.

```
Ext.define('SOMECLASSNAME', {
    extend: 'JSCommon.remoting.RESTService',
    alternateClassName: 'AccountSettingService',

    requires: [
        'JSCommon.security.Privilege',
        'JSCommon.security.PrivilegeConstants',
        'JSCommon.security.store.UIPrivilege',
        'JSCommon.util.StringUtil'
    ],

    statics: {
        /**
         * Creates and returns a new instance of the ReportsService
         */
        getNewInstance: function() {
            return Ext.create('JSCommon.acctSetting.AccountSettingService');
        }
    },

    config: {
        customer: 'abc',
        service: 'companySetting'
    },

    constructor: function(config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
        return this;
    },

    getCompanyID: function() {
        return PlatformCache.getCompanyContextByAttribute('id');
    },

    getAccountSetting: function(onResult, onFault) {
        var me = this;
        var svc = RESTService.getNewInstance();
        var ops = Ext.create('JSCommon.remoting.URLElements');
        var params = Ext.create('JSCommon.remoting.URLParams');

        params.add('action', 'find');
        var postbody = {
        };

        svc.sendGETRequest(svc.getURL(this.getCustomer(), me.getCompanyID(), me.getService(), ops, params), postbody, onResult, onFault);
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you had a go at Rhino?

Comment: In case it can help, [here](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/jsonschema/util/RhinoHelper.java) is a simple class that I wrote -- I can get handles to the two functions, but your case is a little more complex

Comment: How would I use Rhino? I saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658569/using-rhinos-javascript-parser-how-to-get-the-comments but AstRoot doesn't seem to be an actual class in Rhino (or perhaps I just have the wrong version?).

Answer (score 0):

As you do not try to parse the complete javascript language, you might not need a full blown javascript engine. Have you had a look at ANTLR? As you can simplify your problem to a hand full of properties (if I understood you correctly) I'd think you should be able to write a more or less simple grammar for your problem.